# How to declare a 2D array in verilog? I want to take a 4x4 matrix as an input

Tags: algorithm, encryption, verilog

I am creating a AES verilog code, and I need to collect 16 input [7:0] each one in a 4x4 matrix, so I need to define it and implement the initialization of the matrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking how to create Verilog inputs to take that array, you could have multiple inputs, packed arrays or in some cases unpacked arrays.

Multiple inputs:

```
module aes (
  input [7:0] data_1,
  input [7:0] data_2,
  //...
  input [7:0] data_16
);
```

Unpacked Array

```
module aes #(
  parameter DATA_W = 8,
  parameter BYTE_COUNT = 16,
) (
  input [DATA_W*BYTE_COUNT -1:0] data
);
```

Packed Array, not as common as the other types:

```
module aes #(
  parameter DATA_W = 8,
  parameter BYTE_COUNT = 16,
) (
  input [DATA_W-1:0] data [0:BYTE_COUNT-1]
);
```

I am not sure how well multi-dimensional arrays are supported as ports, but in SystemVerilog 2001 Multi dimensional Array types are supported.

To hold the data as a 4x4 Array:

```
reg [7:0] data [0:3][0:3];
```

If this is not an input matrix but bit shifted in and stored in flip-flops the initialization would be done by a reset signal or another clear signal, for an asynchronous reset :

```
integer x, y;
always @(posedge clk or negede rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    for (x=0,x<4,x=x+1) begin
      for (y=0,y<4,y=y+1) begin
        data[x][y] <= 8'h00 ;
      end
    end
  end
  else begin
    //Control on rising edge of clk
  end
end
```

NB: The for loops are unrolled at compilation time there is nothing dynamic in the hardware.